# How to create a recursive computed property in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write my first ember application. It is a Google Chrome extension that replace the new tab. When the app is loaded from the index route it works correctly. When I reopen a closed tab that was on the route of a subfolder (i.e. with a url of this type chrome-extension://thechromeextensionhash/index.html#/3) an error occurs.

The error is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of null

at the line

```
path = path.concat(this.get('folder').get('path')); // inside the path computed property
```

This is the affected code:

```
// models/folder.js

App.Folder = DS.Model.extend({

  title: DS.attr('string'),

  level: DS.attr(),

  files: DS.hasMany('file', {
    async: true
  }),

  folders: DS.hasMany('folder', {
    async: true
  }),

  folder: DS.belongsTo('folder'),

  prefixedId: function() {
    return "folder-" + this.get('id');
  }.property('id'),

  path: function() {
    var path = [];
    if (this.get('level') !== 0) {
      path = path.concat(this.get('folder').get('path'));
    }
    path.push(this);
    return path;
  }.property('level', 'folder', 'folder.path')

});


App.Folder.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Root',
    level: 0,
    bookmarks: [],
    files: [2, 3],
    folder: null
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Folder 1',
    level: 1,
    files: [1, 2],
    folders: [],
    folder: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Folder 2',
    level: 1,
    files: [3, 4],
    folders: [4],
    folder: 1
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'Folder 4',
    level: 2,
    files: [],
    folders: [],
    folder: 3
  }
];
```

This is the index route:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function(){
    var rootFolder = this.store.find('folder', 1);
    this.transitionTo('folder', rootFolder);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

folder should be async

```
folder: DS.belongsTo('folder', {
  async: true
}),
```

Additionally, folder can be null,

```
  var parentFolder = this.get('folder');
  if (Ember.isEmpty(parentFolder){
    //do something else
  } else {
    // not empty
  }
```

So since folder is a promise/null upfront you can't depend on level to let you know the folder exists

```
path: function() {
  var path = [],
      parPath = this.get('folder.path');

  if (parPath) {
    path = path.concat(parPath);
  }
  path.push(this);

  return path;
}.property('folder', 'folder.path'),
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/93/edit

Comment: By setting folder as async I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '__ember1388576555550_meta' of undefined